# Closing all open Excel files without saving

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

I've got about 50 Excel documents open. None of them are saved nor do I want to save any of them.

If I right click Excel in Taskbar and click Close All Windows I can achieve my goal but then need to go to each individual document to click "Don't Save". Is there a quicker way?

Comment: you could try terminating the process through Tsak Manager

Comment: I'm amazed that this question has not received many views. I have wasted countless minutes trying to close Excel windows without killing the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can terminate all excel processes using the following command in command prompt:

```
taskkill /im excel.exe /f
```

Answer (score 6):

Press close button while holding `Shift` key, then press `Don't save` (still holding `Shift`).

Comment: that's a nifty little trick